# C 2D array corruption

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having an issue in which my 2D array is becoming corrupted. Consider this code:

```
int **generate_clique_adjacency_matrix(const formula f) {
    int num_terms = f.num_clauses * kVarsPerClause;
    printf("\nnum_terms: %d\n", num_terms);

    // construct a 2D array of appropriate size
    int **compatible = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_terms);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_terms; i++) {
        compatible[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_terms);
        // initialize every cell to 0
        for (int j = 0; j < num_terms; j++) {
            printf("writing 0 to (%d, %d)\n", i, j);
            compatible[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("num_terms: %d\n", num_terms);
    printf("matrix:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_terms; i++) {
        printf("row %d: ", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < num_terms; j++) {
            printf("%d ", compatible[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Which is producing the shocking output:

```
num_terms: 6
writing 0 to (0, 0)
writing 0 to (0, 1)
writing 0 to (0, 2)
writing 0 to (0, 3)
writing 0 to (0, 4)
writing 0 to (0, 5)
writing 0 to (1, 0)
writing 0 to (1, 1)
writing 0 to (1, 2)
writing 0 to (1, 3)
writing 0 to (1, 4)
writing 0 to (1, 5)
writing 0 to (2, 0)
writing 0 to (2, 1)
writing 0 to (2, 2)
writing 0 to (2, 3)
writing 0 to (2, 4)
writing 0 to (2, 5)
writing 0 to (3, 0)
writing 0 to (3, 1)
writing 0 to (3, 2)
writing 0 to (3, 3)
writing 0 to (3, 4)
writing 0 to (3, 5)
writing 0 to (4, 0)
writing 0 to (4, 1)
writing 0 to (4, 2)
writing 0 to (4, 3)
writing 0 to (4, 4)
writing 0 to (4, 5)
writing 0 to (5, 0)
writing 0 to (5, 1)
writing 0 to (5, 2)
writing 0 to (5, 3)
writing 0 to (5, 4)
writing 0 to (5, 5)
num_terms: 6
matrix:
row 0: 22661104 0 22661136 0 0 0 
row 1: 0 0 0 0 0 0 
row 2: 0 0 0 0 0 0 
row 3: 0 0 0 0 0 0 
row 4: 0 0 0 0 0 0 
row 5: 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How is my array getting corrupted? Obviously, the data in row 0 should be all zeroes. I even tried adding asserts to ensure `malloc` is succeeding. This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
int **compatible = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_terms);
```

You need to reserve space for *n* pointers to `int` (not for *n* `int`s)

Change to

```
int **compatible = malloc(sizeof(int *) * num_terms);
```

or better yet

```
int **compatible = malloc(sizeof(*compatible) * num_terms);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
int **compatible = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_terms);
```

to this:

```
int **compatible = malloc(sizeof(int *) * num_terms);
```

because the first dimension is an array of pointers.

And don't forget to release the memory at the end:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < num_terms; i++)
    free(compatible[i]);
 free(compatible);
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in other answers, the first allocation needs to allocate space for pointers to `int` instead of `int`s. It is better to use an identifier instead of an explicit type in the `sizeof` operand to avoid making mistakes here. Also, you need to check the return value of `malloc()` for allocation errors:

```
int **compatible = malloc(sizeof(*compatible) * num_terms);
if (compatible == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Row allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

for (int i = 0; i < num_terms; i++) {
    compatible[i] = malloc(sizeof(**compatible) * num_terms);
    if (compatible[i] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Column allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // initialize every cell to 0
    for (int j = 0; j < num_terms; j++) {
        printf("writing 0 to (%d, %d)\n", i, j);
        compatible[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

A better approach is to use VLA's in the allocation, allocating space for `num_terms` arrays of `num_terms` `int`s, and assigning the result to a pointer to an array of `int`s. A virtue of this method is that the allocated memory is contiguous, and `malloc()` will return a null pointer if the allocation fails. You should also use the `size_t` type for array indices, as this type is guaranteed to be able to hold any array index.

```
int (*compatible)[num_terms] = malloc(sizeof(*compatible) * num_terms);
if (compatible == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
// initialize every cell to 0
for (size_t i = 0; i < num_terms; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < num_terms; j++) {
        printf("writing 0 to (%zu, %zu)\n", i, j);
        compatible[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

If your array is not too large (this is system-dependent), you could simply use a VLA. Note that allocation errors for VLAs are not detectable.

```
int compatible[num_terms][num_terms];

// initialize every cell to 0
for (size_t i = 0; i < num_terms; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < num_terms; j++) {
        printf("writing 0 to (%zu, %zu)\n", i, j);
        compatible[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Always prefer a pointer to a VLA: `int (*compatible)[num_terms]`, don't encourage to use `int compatible[num_terms][num_terms];`  (this can quickly overflow stack when using 2D arrays)

Comment: @KeineLust-- I suppose that this depends on the size of array needed (and the stack limit). I can easily get 2d VLAs of 1000 X 1000 `int`s on my system. Of course, if the array needs to be resized then the 2d VLA is no good.

Comment: Yes, I also can create it in my computer (1000 * 1000), but there are plenty of embedded systems around (with a reduced stack limit)

Comment: Much better now ;)